# Get existing process handle

Tags: c++, windows

Let's say I'm a DLL that's inside a certain process **(process A**) that already haves a handle to another one (**the target, process B**). I wanna get the existing handle of process B from process A (I'm a DLL injected in process A) to use `ReadProcessMemory()` on Process B.

How can I do that? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: what information you have about process B ? say it process id or what ? and why you can not or not want yourself open process B ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `QuerySystemInformation` with the `SystemHandleInformation` class (`0x10`) to get a list of handles, iterate over them and look for the `ProcessId` to process B. Most lot of the structures are undocumented but readily available on the web.

Comment: @BenVoigt no that's not the point. The OP wants to directly use/hijack a `HANDLE` the process he's injected into has already opened.

Comment: It does matter because some processes prevent you from opening a handle to them or its strip permissions unless your process is signed or a part of windows (csrss.exe, lsass.exe). What I described in my answer is a way to hijack a process handle to process B from process A which allows you to then read/write/allocate memory/etc.

Comment: better of course use `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` (0x40). *and look for the ProcessId to process B* - yes, but need explain how. first of all need determinate `ObjectTypeIndex` for process type - say open handle for self process before query and search for this handle, look it index. then search for opened process (by `ObjectTypeIndex`) handles. for every handle we need check `GrantedAccess` - it must have at least `PROCESS_QUERY[_LIMITED]_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_VM_READ` and then need query `ProcessBasicInformation` for this handle for compare it id with `B` process

Comment: but for what all this, if we can simply open process handle by id. if `A` already open handle to `B` and we inside `A` - why we can not again open `B` ?